# Description for each module type in suiteCRM

Tags: suitecrm

It seems like such a simple thing, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

There's a couple of dozen of different module types in suiteCRM (sugarCRM CE), but I can't find an explainer file that lists all of them. Not in official application guide or in source code (for example there's nothing about "Line Items")

Does anyone know if a complete list exists somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of modules.

1) Admin only modules.

2) Core System modules.

3) User modules.

Admin only modules are only visible by admin of SugarCRM. Core system modules like studio ,module builder are back-bone modules of the application so they are not listed to anyone.

Rest modules are users modules, like leads/accounts etc.
They are visible to everyone depends upon their role and role permissions.

you need to see a complete list of modules in 2 locations.

1) include/modules.php

2) custom/application/Ext/include/modules.ext.ph

If you want to see the complete list, there is a global variable called $moduleList. just print it somewhere.

Comment: thanks Ashish, but I already have a list of them and that file doesn't provide a description for each module only a list of modules